# Conditional not passing in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I've got a pretty simple batch script, but for some reason the conditional isn't working like I'm expecting:

```
SET RIG=%1
IF /I RIG==Polar (
    SET SQLSERVER=SQL01
    SET MONITOR=SQL02
    SET TESTSETTING="test"
    SET TESTCONTAINER="test2 
) ELSE ( 
    ECHO Your input was %1.
)
```

When I pass the following command: `testrun.bat Polar` I get the `ECHO` statement returned: `Your input was Polar.`"

I've tried putting the `%1` in quotations, messing with the way parentheses are laid out, and I've reviewed ss64.com's syntax for batch script IF statements, but I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: You need `%RIG%` not `RIGNAME`.

Comment: Just saw that in the answer below. I feel dumb, because I use variables elsewhere in this same script.

Answer (score 1):

`RIGNAME` is never going to be equal to `Polar`

Now you could try assigning the value to `rigname` rather than `rig`.

Even then, yu'd need to compare `%rigname%` to `Polar` to access the `content` of `rigname` rather than the string `RIGNAME`.

Comment: Holy crap. I use variables all over the place elsewhere in this same script, but somehow missed that. Beautiful, thanks. That makes perfect sense. Also the Rigname/Rig thing was just a typo on my part, in writing this. I'll fix that in the question.